# How to update root certificates in Windows 7 installation ISO?

Tags: windows-7, iso-image, certificate, integration, slipstream

I want to integrate current certificates (root, disallowed) into Windows 7 installation ISO.
I have integrated (using dism) latest updates and drivers (mass storage + usb 3.x) and stucked with certs.

How to do it and what cert files do I need:
rootsupd.exe
authrootstl.cab
disallowedcertstl.cab
?

PS I can unpack rootsupd.exe and run 4 commands:
updroots.exe authroots.sst
updroots.exe updroots.sst
updroots.exe -l roots.sst
updroots.exe -d delroots.sst
...but how to "inject" it into installation ISO?

Comment: Use DISM to create a new .wim installation image.

Comment: I repeat my question: How to integrate certs using DISM?

Comment: Create a .wim image from your current installation with them already installed

Comment: I want to integrate certs into Windows 7 ISO file - not into already installed system which is so simple, that I wouldn't ask for it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't mean to necro, but you have no definitive answer.

The short answer is that you cannot directly import a certificate into an installer, or directly into a WIM file.  There just is not a method to do so.

However, as @Ramhound mentioned, you can build a new OS installer with the certificate in place.  You'll have to install Windows, and before finishing the initial setup, enter into Audit Mode, and make your modifications there.  Run through Sysprep, and capture your new WIM.

You could rename the new WIM to install.wim, and maybe replace it on the Windows 7 ISO file, but your mileage may vary, as I've had installations fail due to signature mismatch on the WIM file.